# Can't Import iMovie to Final Cut Pro X on Mavericks

Tags: imovie, final-cut-pro

In FCP I went to file>Import>Import iMovie Project.  However, I've searched everywhere and I can't find my iMovie project to import.  Some people suggested looking in the movies folder.  Below is a screenshot of my movies folder.

I'm using Final Cut Pro X version 10.0.8 and iMovie 10.0.4.  My OS is 10.9.4

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open iMovie and select the iMovie Project that you wish to send to Final Cut Pro 10.1. Simply use FILE/SEND Movie to Final Cut Pro. In your case you just need to update your Final Cut Pro to the latest version.

Note: This will not work if you’re not on the FCP 10.1.